# how to find count in foreach loop?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i want to count comments at every article ..but the comments counter place between foreach loop..so i cant count comments correctly...so i want loop but i dont need loop in the counter

articles_controller.php

```
$count = $this->Article->Comment->find(
    'count', array('conditions' =>  array('Comment.status' => 1))
);
```

articles/index.ctp

```
<?php
// initialise a counter for striping the table
$count = 0;

// loop through and display format
foreach($articles as $article):
    // stripes the table by adding a class to every other row
    $class = ( ($count % 2) ? " class='altrow'": '' );
    // increment count
    $count++;

?>

<?php 
    echo $html->link(
        $article['Article']['title'], 
        array( 'action' => 'view', $article['Article']['id'])
    );  
?>

<!-- date and comment counter -->
<p class="entry-meta">
    <span class="date"><?php echo $article['Article']['created']; ?></span> <span class="meta-sep">|</span>
    <span class="comments-link">
    <!-- here i will put the comment counter -->
    <a href="declining-health.html#respond"> <?php  echo $count ['Comment'];>Comments</a>
    </span>
</p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the counterCache property in the Post->Comment relationship and make sure you have a comment_count field in the post model.

IE:

```
<?php
    class Post extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'Post';
        public $hasMany = array(
            'Comment' => array(
                'className'    => 'Comment',
                'foreignKey'   => 'post_id'
            )
        );
    }
?>

<?php
    class Comment extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'Comment';
        public $belongsTo = array(
            'Post' => array(
                'className'    => 'Comment',
                'counterCache'   => true
            )
        );
    }
?>
// in the database table for table posts make sure to do the following

add a column: comment_count int(11) default 0
```

Now when you add a new post, you will have a comment_count field with an initial value of 0. When a new comment is added or removed from a Post the count value will automagically update.

That allows you to simply loop over the posts array and echo the value of the comment_count field or use the value to check for comments then embed an element etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of items in an array with `sizeof()`.

Comment: you mean id do this <?php  echo sizeof($count ['Comment']) ;>

Comment: i tjink you dont understand me ... the count i mean not function but mysql code like this SELECT COUNT

Comment: What is the problem then? You can do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl` to get the number of rows in the table `tbl`.

Comment: ok but the result between foreach loop.. i dont need to loop this result

Comment: You can do `sizeof($arr)` without first having looped through `$arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Krisitian gave you the answer, but may I suggest you do all your styling in the frontend.

**css pseudo selector**

```
//styles every second(even) elements
.your_class:nth-child(2n){background-color:hotpink;}

tr:nth-child(2n){background-color:hotpink;}

...these also work with jquery
```